# Why not from database hour and minute is not showing exact the same?

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in database Called CarrierDeliveryStartDateHour what I want to achieve is to show 3:45 PM or AM depending on the time of course.

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'hh:mm tt') AS CarrierDeliveryStartDateHour
```

I am using this query. But the problem is when I make a query from the database it is showing the wrong time, for example, 2:00 AM instead it should show 3:45 I think we should apply timezone and offset. any idea, please

Comment: `GETUTCDATE()` show the database time zone offset is not included.

Comment: i had to make function to solve but you i think you are closer to answer.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[sfUtcToLocal] 
(
    @UtcDatetime        DATETIMEOFFSET,
    @IDTimeZone         typIDTimeZone
)
RETURNS DATETIMEOFFSET
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @UTCoffset          typUTCoffset

SELECT @UTCoffset = COALESCE(ttzd.UTCoffset, ttz.UTCoffset)
FROM tabTimeZone AS ttz
    LEFT JOIN tabTimeZoneDST AS ttzd ON ttzd.IDTimeZone = ttz.IDTimeZone
        AND @UtcDatetime BETWEEN ttzd.StartDate AND ttzd.EndDate
WHERE ttz.IDTimeZone = @IDTimeZone
    AND ttz.[Deleted] = 0

RETURN ISNULL(SWITCHOFFSET (@UtcDatetime, @UTCoffset), @UtcDatetime)
```

END